# Divergence theorem on vector function generated by integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, electromagnetism

Suppose we define the magnetic field as $B(r) = \frac{1}{c}\int_{V}d^3r' \frac{J(r') \times(r-r')}{|r-r'|^3} $

Show that $\nabla \dot{}B=0$

I tried applying divergence theorem.

$\int_{V} \nabla \dot{} B d^3r' = \int_{S} d^2r'n \dot{}B$

Not exactly sure how to find this result, some insight would be helpful.

Comment: A little googling and.. http://www.physicspages.com/2013/03/04/divergence-of-magnetic-field-magnetic-monopoles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hint for you. Write the $(r - r')/\lvert r - r'\rvert^3$ vector field as the gradient of a well-chosen scalar function. Then, noting that the del operator is being taken with respect to the unprimed coordinates, move it under the integral, and using the fact that $\nabla\cdot(A\times C) = C\cdot(\nabla\times A) - A\cdot(\nabla \times C)$, and that the curl of a gradient is always zero, conclude that your integrand is zero. Conclude that $\nabla \cdot B = 0$.

Comment: Totally saw it once you put this down nicely. Thank you very much for the help.